# VBA Alternatives to workbook.open to pull data from a single cell

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wanted to find out if anyone can recommend an alternative way to query data in an excel file from an MS Access module.

If I have a data organised in a typical "Table" format e.g rows and columns with headers, then I have been connecting to the workbook using a DAO connection as below

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rsUsers as DAO.Recordset

Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\SaleLog.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;")
Set rsUsers = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT userID FROM [Sales$]")
```

I find this preferable to using

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\SaleLog.xls", True, False
```

As it does not physically open an instance of an excel session and therefore runs a bit more quickly.

The only problem is when the data is not laid out like a table (e.g if I just wanted to get the value of 1 particular cell).
Does anyone know if there is a way to check the value of a cell in VBA without using `Workbook.Open`?

Comment: What about linking to the spreadsheet as a linked table ?

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/645172-visual-basic-applications-code-pulling-data-closed-workbook-w-o-opening.html

Comment: Hi @Minty , unfortunately as mentioned, the data is not laid out like a table so I cannot link to the data in this way.

Comment: Hi @JohnMuggins  If I understand that link correctly, the code would work to update a cell in 1 workbook with data from a cell in a different workbook. I am trying to query the data in excel from an access database so I'm not sure I can adapt that code for my needs

Comment: Is it a nomenclature issue?  I don't know Access well but do know that some of the excel VBA doesn't transfer over well.

Comment: I apologize for not knowing Access well.  But do you have the same "record macro" as in Excel?  If so this link might help you achieve what you want.  Alternatively when working with a slow server I once changed all the worker bee data to delimited text files, which the main supervisor workbook could open and populate cells within a fraction of the time.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428358/import-data-from-excel-into-ms-access

Comment: Hi @JohnMuggins Thanks for your efforts. The first link you provided has two solutions, 1 uses an ExecuteExcel4Macro function which is returning an error 2029. I'm unsure if this is due to not working from Access but I'll play around with it. The other solution is entering the filepath of the other workbook in a cell in the current workbook which doesn't apply here. The Second link mentions linking to the data with a docmd.transferspreadsheet method which again I think will only work if it is laid out like a table

Comment: Well, yes, there may not be an exact answer, you might have to pick and choose bits from here and there to get it the way you need it.

Comment: Maybe another shot... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ImportExportSpreadsheet-Macro-Action-9973a631-6586-4c1d-9c61-ae167696b750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a simpler way to achieve this but I have found 3 methods which can be used to pull data into MS Access from a single cell in a closed Excel workbook relatively efficiently (Many thanks to John Muggins for his help with this).

Firstly, the `workbooks.open` method can be used and will run more quickly if you set the read-only parameter to true (I'm unsure if this technically 'Opens' the workbook but it definitely seems to run more quickly while read-only). This requires you to set a reference to the Excel library.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim src As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set src = xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\SaleLog.xls", True, True
```

You can then get data from specific cells using normal Excel VBA syntax like so

```
strUser = src.Worksheets("Sales").Range("B8")

src.Close False  'false doesn't save changes
Set src = Nothing
```

Another method is to use the `DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet` method to link or import a single cell, in this case you would need to set the HasFieldNames parameter to false as shown

```
path = "C:\SaleLog.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblTemp", path, False, "Sales!B8:B8"
```

This will create a table with a single field called F1. You can get the value stored in this table using a DLookup or a recordset (You may then wish to delete the temp table e.g. `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblTemp"`).

Lastly you can use a DAO connection as mentioned in the original question. You can specify a specific cell like so

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rsUsers as DAO.Recordset

Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\SaleLog.xls", False, True, "Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;")
Set rsUsers = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Sales$B8:B8]")
```

Again this will create a recordset with a single field called F1. You can get the value of this field by using `rsUsers.Fields("F1")`

Each of the above methods can be (*and usually are*) used to pull data from an entire worksheet or range of cells but for the purpose of this question I wanted to show how they can be used to pull data from a single cell. I haven't tested them for efficiency although I doubt there is much difference in speed between them so probably best to go with the method that you find simplest.

If anyone knows how to tweak any of these methods to make them more efficient or has another approach altogether please feel free to comment or add a new answer :)